# Magento 2: Add VIP pricing that's always 5% off normal pricing?

Tags: magento2, php

I'm trying to add a new line of pricing info to my Magento 2 website, for example, if regular price of an item is $10, it will show "VIP price: $9" under the regular pricing, the new price will always be a fixed % off the retail price. And I need this new price to show on both product listing and on product details page.

This price doesn't need to be used on checkout as it's purely for information only. Can anyone point out which direction I should go?

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this, I'd recommend you to read throught dev docs anyways :

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-price-group.html